# Writing mixed text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, language, input-languages

In Word, while writing japanese using a japanese font sometimes I have to write also some romaji, and when I do it automatically switches to a different font for that text only.

This is particularly tedious when writing something in romaji inside parentheses because the first one will be in the normal font while the text inside and the last one will be rendered with another font, like this:

[image]

How can I tell the application not to switch font by itself?

Comment: Word 2013 automatically switches between MS Mincho and Calibri (the default Body Asian and Body fonts) for me, and I'd suggest that's the intended behaviour, as Japanese fonts aren't designed for Latin characters. The left bracket in your screenshot looks like a [fullwidth character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff08/index.htm) to me, while the right bracket looks like a regular [right parenthesis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/29/index.htm).

Comment: Even if you never used Calibri you would still have the same problem. The way you are inputting the text is producing different types of brackets for the left and right side. It has nothing to do with font at all. You're conflating two different questions. (I can replicate this behavior here in this textbox. The IME assumes fullwidth following the kana, and switches to halfwidth when romaji is entered.)

Comment: For me, I can fix this behavior by entering, instead of `guguru(GUGURU)`, `guguru` + ENTER + Shift-CAPSLOCK(romaji mode) + `(GUGURU)` + Ctrl-CAPSLOCK(kana mode) ; or, alternatively, `guguru` + ENTER + `(` + SPACE(convert to halfwidth bracket) + `GUGURU)` ... there are probably other ways too. Anyway, that is an IME problem and not an application one, and separate from the font issue.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize it. So to solve the bracket question I suppose I just have to type the closing one separately. This of course will display nicely if the text inside is using same font, as my original question.

Comment: There are other systems (e.g. [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page)) in which you can type plain text and you have full control over the font used for each (range of) Unicode character(s). I don't think this is possible automatically in Word. You will have to turn your IME on/off for Word to understand that you want a different font.

Comment: related, possibly duplicate: [Changing text format based on language](https://superuser.com/q/597188/241386), [How to convert Japanese characters into roman characters when you accidentally type an English word with Japanese input turned on (on Windows)](https://superuser.com/q/829427/241386)