# Changing text format based on language

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have this large MS Word document which contains irregularly formatted text that contains both arabic and english words.

What I want to do is to format this document based on language. Ex: All text in arabic should be 16pt bold and all text in english should be in 14pt italic.

I want to select  all text of a particular langauge so I can change the font. Ability to select all text of a particular font would also be useful since two languages use two different fonts.

Any idea how to do this without going through the whole document manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have applied language formatting to all of the text, you should be able to do this via Find/Replace.

In Find->Replace, click the "More > > " button if necessary to show the bottom part of the dialog.

Click in the "Find What" box, then click "No Formatting." Then click Format->Language..., and select the language, e.g. Arabic (In the case of Arabic, I think you will need to specify the variant you have used. If you have used more than one, you may need to repeat this process for each).

Then click in the "Replace With". Click "No Formatting" again to clear any formatting. Then click Format->Font... This is where the "catch" is: if you want to specify the font size for the LTR text, you need to specify it in the "Size:" box of the "Latin text" section of the dialog (you can probably ignore the fact that there is also an "Asian text" label there - both types of text share a size. If you want to specify the font size for the RTL text, you need to use the "Size:" box in the "Complex Scripts" section of the dialog.

After that, you should be able to use Replace All to modify the size of all the LTR or RTL text.

If you get that far, it may look as if you could replace the sizes of both types of text all in one by specifying both sizes in "Replace With" and no language in "Find What", but it doesn't work because the relevant buttons remain greyed until you select *something* in the Find What box.

Answer (score 0):

The following option on the **Home** tab (in Word 2010/2013 at least) might help you:

[image: 1]

Note that you'll need to select some text first, then click that option to select all text in the document with similar formatting.

Comment: Nope, tried it, didn't do good. "select text with similar formatting" selects parts of document that are already in a similar format but word decides what is "similar". What I want to do is to find text based on a specific attribute of the text that I select.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in the following steps.

1. select the whole contents of your typed word document by pushing Ctr+A buttons.
2. go to Formant/ Font menu.
3. select Font, Font type and Font size for Latin and Complex scripts.

It is done.

Comment: The question is how to select only Arabic/ English text respectively. Your answer doesn't address it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).